transition on grid-template-columns fr to px value
I have this HTML / CSS snippet:


.test123 {
  grid-template-columns: 255px 255px;
  transition: 200ms;
  display: grid;
  gap: 30px;
  .card {
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #BBD0FB;
  }
  .c1 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .c2 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
  }
}
.test123:has(:nth-child(1):hover) {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 255px;
}
.test123:has(:nth-child(2):hover) {
  grid-template-columns: 255px 1fr;
}
<div class="test123">
        <div class="card c1"></div>
        <div class="card c2"></div>
</div>



I want the blue and red cards to have some transition when they are hovered, so they would smoothly grow and shrink.
I tried to allow transition-behaviour: allow-discrete but it did not help, so I am kind of stuck with this issue.
Thank you

Well, the easiest way is to do the browser's job. Looking at your code, I would advise you to keep it simple.


.test123 {
  grid-template-columns: 255px 255px;
  transition: 200ms;
  display: grid;
  gap: 30px;
  .card {
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #BBD0FB;
  }
  .c1 {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
  }
  .c2 {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
  }
}

.test123:has(:nth-child(1):hover) {
  grid-template-columns: calc(100% - 255px - 30px) 255px;
}

.test123:has(:nth-child(2):hover) {
  grid-template-columns: 255px calc(100% - 255px - 30px);
}
<div class="test123">
  <div class="card c1"></div>
  <div class="card c2"></div>
</div>




Thank you, I am going with this answer since I asked for CSS grid solution and this is working solution and also smooth animation. Thank you

You can transite from 0fr to 1fr but restrict their min-width to 255px


.test123 {
  grid-template-columns: 0fr 0fr;
  transition: 200ms;
  display: grid;
  gap: 30px;
  
  .card {
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #BBD0FB;
  }
  .c1 {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 255px;
  }
  .c2 {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100px;
    min-width: 255px;
  }
}

.test123:has(:nth-child(1):hover) {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 0fr;
}

.test123:has(:nth-child(2):hover) {
  grid-template-columns: 0fr 1fr;
}
<div class="test123">
  <div class="card c1"></div>
  <div class="card c2"></div>
</div>




This works but if you comapare with another answer below of Andrei Fedorov (https://stackoverflow.com/a/79198619/13935477), it is more fluid solution without glitches when you fast-hover from one card to another.

This is a flexbox job


.test123 {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  gap: 30px;
  .card {
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 1px solid #BBD0FB;
    flex-basis: 255px;
    transition: .2s;
  }
  .card:hover {
     flex-grow: 1;
   }
  .c1 {
    background-color: red;
  }
  .c2 {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
<div class="test123">
        <div class="card c1"></div>
        <div class="card c2"></div>
</div>




Totally agree that it is a flexbox job, but I was curious how to make it work using grid. Thanks for you contribution
